# gganimate returns .png files, but no animated object

Tags: ggplot2, rendering, gganimate

I am trying to create an animation to show students how to represent data with animations. 
Running the below code

```
library(ggplot)
library(gganimate)
library(carData)        
anim <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
          transition_states(gear, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
          enter_fade() +
          exit_fade()

    animate(anim)
```

I was expecting an animation on a preview window and the creation of a gif image.

Conversely, what I am getting is 100 .png files in the working directory, but nothing else. The pictures are correct and are the frames of the animation, they are just not put together by the function.
In particular I get 100 elements of which I show the first elements here:
This list

```
  [1] "./gganim_plot0001.png" "./gganim_plot0002.png" "./gganim_plot0003.png" 
  [4] "./gganim_plot0004.png" "./gganim_plot0005.png" "./gganim_plot0006.png"
  [7] "./gganim_plot0007.png" "./gganim_plot0008.png" "./gganim_plot0009.png"
 [10] "./gganim_plot0010.png" "./gganim_plot0011.png" "./gganim_plot0012.png"...
```

And

```
    attr(,"frame_vars")
    frame nframes progress transitioning previous_state closest_state
1       1     100     0.01         FALSE              3             3
2       2     100     0.02         FALSE              3             3
3       3     100     0.03         FALSE              3             3
```

and

```
next_state
1            3
2            3
3            3
4            3
5            3
6            3
7            3
8            3
9            3
10           3
11           3
12           3
```

And finally this

```
 frame_source
1   C:\\Users\\rosar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpIR4dH3\\3b84232b4eef/gganim_plot0001.png
2   C:\\Users\\rosar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpIR4dH3\\3b84232b4eef/gganim_plot0002.png
3   C:\\Users\\rosar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpIR4dH3\\3b84232b4eef/gganim_plot0003.png
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

make sure you have one of the packages required to combine images into videos. I'd advice you to use gifski:

```r
install.packages('gifski')
install.packages('png')
```

and restart R

Comment: It would be nice if gganimate gives an error that one of these packages is missing