# How can I see the animated result?

Tags: r, gganimate

I have been trying to plot an animation which will show the number of refugees over the years. The code runs without issues, but it won't show the output animation. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
animation <- refugees_clean %>% 
ggplot( aes(x=year, y=number, group= origin_region, color=origin_region)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point() +
scale_color_discrete() +
ggtitle("Refugee numbers over the years") +
theme_dark() +
ylab("Number of refugees") +
transition_reveal(year)
animation
dput(head(refugees_clean))
structure(list(origin_country = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Armenia", 
"Azerbaijan", "Belarus", "Bhutan"), iso3 = c("AFG", "AGO", "ARM", 
"AZE", "BLR", "BTN"), origin_region = c("South Asia", "Sub-Saharan 
Africa", 
"Europe & Central Asia", "Europe & Central Asia", "Europe & Central 
Asia", 
"South Asia"), origin_continent = c("Asia", "Africa", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Europe", "Asia"), year = c(2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
 2006), number = c(651, 13, 87, 77, 350, 3), year_date = 
 structure(c(13149, 
 13149, 13149, 13149, 13149, 13149), class = "Date")), row.names = 
 c(NA, 
 -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you share data to make this reproducible? Could you edit your question with `dput(head(refugees_clean))` for example?

Comment: Can you describe what your code does currently? What output do you get? Are you getting a list of image filenames, for example?

Comment: The code output produces a series of .png files and I don't know where these are being saved either.

Comment: I believe you need to use `animate(animation)` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gganimate/versions/1.0.6/topics/animate), and I would save it directly to a .gif with `anim_save` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gganimate/versions/1.0.6/topics/anim_save)

Comment: Also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991580/gganimate-returns-png-files-but-no-animated-object and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664377/gganimate-plot-not-showing-and-saving-bunch-of-pngs